# Cocos2d-x (JS) Android JavaScript Remote Debugging

Tags: cocos2d-x, remote-debugging, cocos2d-js, firefox-developer-tools

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Javascript_Remote_Debugging
As per above doc, I tried the same for Android, but didnt work. From firefox, on clicking 'connect', connect to remote device screen came pre-filled with ip 127.0.0.1 and port 5086. After running the app on device and trying to connect, it shows unexpected error. 
Has anyone made it working?

Comment: experiencing the same issue. did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Remote debugging of Cocos2d-x version 3.x games only works with Firefox version 36. Luckily, it is still available at https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/36.0/.
The current Firefox happily lives with version 36, just remember to keep both versions when your o/s asks. To keep them straight, I named version 36, "Firefox36".